# Safari bookmark to activate an Automator action

Tags: applescript, automator

I'm trying to make a HTML page that I can save as a bookmark in Safari or Google Chrome that runs an Automator workflow, action or application, or possibly an Applescript.

It's only for my personal computer and I want to use the simplest possible approach to accomplishing this.

Comment: I don't think that this would get past the secure sandboxes of either browser. Why not just a link on the desktop or dock? What does the workflow do? Is it talking to the current open page in the browser? Maybe a Javascript bookmarklet is a possibility?

Answer (score 1):

A `file://` link (with the path to your desired program) can point to a workflow, application, or AppleScript on your local drive. Clicking the link will not run the application (this lack of functionality is generally considered to be a desirable security feature), but it *will* open a Finder window and select the file in question, so pressing <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>O</kbd> or <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>↓</kbd> will run the desired program.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea with a local apache server.

1. Install Apache on your machine.
2. Locate Apache access.log
3. Watch the changes on this file with this command, and look after a specific string in the log: here, I am watching the access to my Drupal web application

Type this command in a terminal

```
$ tail -f access_log | awk '/drupal/ {system("/Applications/capture.app/Contents/MacOS/Application\\\ Stub");}'
```

`Capture.app`  is an automator application. It can be anything you want, for example:

```
$ system("say Drupal");  # speech synthesis
$ system("open -R /");   # opens the Finder
```

This is not a clean solution, it processes all the log when it starts, and it's attached to a terminal. Apache has mechanisms to do this with hooks.

You don't even have to have something at the URL. The only important part is the request in acces_log.